# jQuery plugin to position a popup next to a button?

Tags: jquery, plugins

There a multiple buttons, which should invoke the same popup/dropdown list. Is there a jQuery plugin, which would position a currently hidden element next to the clicked button, taking into account the screen limits (so that if the button is at the bottom of the page, the popup is above it)?

I want to place it at the bottom, but if there is not enought space - shift it. Same with left/right, resizing of the window.